# Description of google search result not available due to robots.text

Tags: search, robots.txt

I tried to search for my site in google "DailyMuses" and got the following result

[image]

It says that "A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt"

I went to check the contents of robot.text in my web app and the contents is as follows:

```
# See http://www.robotstxt.org/wc/norobots.html for documentation on how to use the robots.txt file
#
# To ban all spiders from the entire site uncomment the next two lines:
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Can anyone advise me on how I can get around this and allow a description to be shown in the google search?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `robots.txt` . Done .

**UPDATE** : To allow search engine to crawl only the index page, use this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /index.php
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

or replace `index.php` with your index file name, such as `index.html` or `index.jsp`

Comment: But I would like to block crawling on the site but still be able to show the description. Is that possible?

Comment: without crawling, how can search engine fetch data from your site? contradicting. How about only allow search engine to crawl your index ?

Comment: Can you advise me on how I can just do that?

Comment: Thanks! BTW what does this mean? Allow: /$

Comment: `/$` means it supports `http://www.example.com/` . Combining `Allow: /index.php` means it supports `http://www.example.com/index.php` .